# XQuery 1.0 Remove Duplicate Node Values

Tags: xquery

I have tried all kinds of variations to remove a node from my Input that is a duplicate.

The current expression I am using is as follows:

```
    <Signers>{
            let $signers := fn:distinct-values($temp.load/*/Signers)
            for $signer in $signers
  return
    <Signer>{
        $signer
    }</Signer>
}</Signers>
```

I have even used $signer/id, $signer/name, etc. but that does not generate the desired output.

Input

```
        <Signers>
           <id>a1546000000xtaqAAA</id>
           <email>jrogers@burlington.com</email>
           <name>Jack Rogers</name>
        </Signers>
        <Signers>
           <id>a1546000000xwNSAAY</id>
           <email>myaddress96@gmail.com</email>
           <name>Walter White</name>
        </Signers>
        <Signers>
           <id>a1546000000xwNSAAY</id>
           <email>myaddress@gmail.com</email>
           <name>Walter White</name>
        </Signers>
```

Current Output

```
    <Signers>
       <Signer>a1546000000xtaqAAAjrogers@burlington.comJack Rogers</Signer>
       <Signer>a1546000000xwNSAAYrichbateman96@gmail.comWalter White</Signer>
    </Signers>
```

Desired Output

```
         <Signers>
           <id>a1546000000xtaqAAA</id>
           <email>jrogers@burlington.com</email>
           <name>Jack Rogers</name>
        </Signers>
        <Signers>
           <id>a1546000000xwNSAAY</id>
           <email>myaddress96@gmail.com</email>
           <name>Walter White</name>
        </Signers>
```

This has to be simple and I know I am overlooking something.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows to select by distinct `id` :

```
<Signers>
{
    /*/Signers[not(id=preceding-sibling::Signers/id)]
}
</Signers>
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/bdf01955b2f671c7abe33ba44e58428c)</kbd>**

Or using `distinct-values()` as you attempted to do :

```
<Signers>
{
    let $ids := fn:distinct-values(/*/Signers/id)
    for $id in $ids
    return
        /*/Signers[id=$id][1]
}
</Signers>
```